# Optional URL-based authorisation to avoid login cookies

Tags: php, security, url, authentication, cookies

Basically, what I want is to use an alternative to the login cookies as they technically *can* be guessed (there are ways to counter this, but why not eliminate the threat completely)?

What I'm thinking of is a system with a big **do not use on public computers** warning that would allow users to auto-login not with a cookie, but by following an URL such as **/login/email@example.com/myPassword**.

What I want to ask is, should I bother creating such a system or would it make even more security flaws? On one hand, the cookie-based one *can* simply request the password again if, for example, the IP or user agent don't match, on the other, I can save quite a lot of DB space by not having to store cookie names.

Comment: I'll also point out that *this too* technically can be guessed.

Comment: Waaait wait wait. You don't want to use cookies because they can be guessed, so you'd go for storing the login name and password *in the URL*? I don't know what to say. It's like improving airline security by providing every passenger with a gun.

Comment: Well, if you don't like cookies, don't use cookies. Append your session token to to the url everywhere, and you're done.

Comment: I only thought about the client-side storage, e.g. it being kept in the browser history. As Simeon pointed out, there are other places where it inevitably gets stored as well. Will mark his answer as accepted when the timer allows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your approach, the user's password is now exposed: in their browser history, in your server logs, to any network sniffing tool, et cetera. Passwords of users should not be in the URL. So no, it's not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, haven't thought about the data being inevitably exposed to other things than the user's browsing history.

Comment: Hopefully he's using SSL, in which case sniffers wouldn't apply, but the rest still would.  +1

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Simeon, but just want to point out a few additional things:

- Cookies *can* be hijacked, you're right, but things like SSL do a good job of preventing this to the extent that its reasonable.
- If you're using SSL, both approaches (yours and cookies) would be hidden from eavesdroppers.
- As Simeon points out, the requested URL happens to be stored in many more places than the cookie would be, making accidental compromise or intentional compromise more likely.
- Somewhat more importantly, however, is that cookies are just randomly generated strings, specific to your site and your site alone, while plaintext passwords are much more valuable.  A plaintext password to your site might be the same password used for hundreds of other sites.  In other words, a compromised cookie has a maximum impact of one site.  A compromised password on the other hand could have much broader implications.
- Because you note guessing, a PHP session ID is much longer than the typical password.  PHP will typically generate session IDs between 27 and 40 characters, 4+ times the size of average passwords.  Moreover, passwords are often able to be found through things like (modified) dictionary attacks in a fraction of the time that a brute force search over the entire search space would take.  In other words, guessing a plaintext password is *a lot* easier than guessing the contents of a cookie, if you're worried about the security of cookies, increase the length and include server side logic to only accept cookies from clients in the same /24 address space.  If you're still worried, force the user to re-authenticate more frequently.